# How to completely remove Apache from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apache, nginx, lamp, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried all the steps in the given in the AskUbuntu forums but all in vain.I removed entire LAMP Stack as well.But Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page loads up.I want to shift to Nginx and try and test my website on to that first. 
AskUbuntu Solutions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over
https://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For a quick solution, just stop the apache process and start nginx, sudo service apache2 stop, sudo service nginx start

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was because the god damn index file was left in the /var/www directory. So the NGINX was running though it showed the apache html file :) So once I removed index.html from the directory it showed the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove --purge apache2 && sudo apt autoremove -y
```

This command removes Apache completely, including its configurations, and then automatically removes any leftover dependencies without manual confirmation.